# ModelForm not saving BooleanField default value

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following Model:

```
class TransType(models.Model):
    typeName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.typeName
```

Whenever I am creating a new object without specifying isActive value, it is saving the object with isActive set to false even though I have set the default to True. What could be the issue here?

EDIT:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'trans:createmode' %}" class="modal-content form-horizontal" id="creator">
  {% csrf_token %} {{ form }}
  <label for="mode" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Transport Mode</label>
  <input type="text" name="typeName" maxlength="200" class="form-control" required="required" id="typeName">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-success pull-right" id="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: show your form code please

Comment: @BearBrown I've added it

Comment: i mean form class, and better with view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using a ModelForm for `TransType` model.
`blank=True` says that the field *can be empty in the form*, is not required.

If the `isActive` will be empty in the form, value will be ' ' and will be treat as `False` by the `BooleanField`, test in django shell:

```
from django.forms.fields import BooleanField
field = BooleanField()
field.to_python('')  # Results False
field.to_python('Test')  # Results True
field.to_python(True)  # Results True
```

Suggestion: You can add `initial=True` in the form field, or remove `blank=True` from the Model fields, so that in the form the field will be required.

Answer (score 0):

HI can you try like this

model.py

```
class TransType(models.Model):
    typeName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.typeName
```

Just remove **blank=True**, i think it must be working.

just go to django shell and do  like

```
object = TransType()
object. typeName = 'test'
object.save()
```

it must be working

Comment: It was not working correctly without the blank=True part. I just added it to check if it would work

Answer (score 0):

default argument is not valid for BooleanField in some versions of Django, so to create BooleanField with default=True if input is nothing, you can use this code:

```
class MyForms(forms.Form):
    bool_field = forms.NullBooleanField(required=False)

    def clean_bool_field(self, default=True):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get("bool_field")
        return default if bool_field is None else use bool_field
```